# AttributeError при попытке получить значение для поля `documents` в сериализаторе `RequestSerializer`

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Пытаюсь разобраться с Django Rest Framework.

Задача - по `GET` вернуть данные, по `POST` записать новые(вернув записанное).
Но при попытке вернуть данные по `GET`, получаю лишь ошибку:

> AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for
> field `documents` on serializer `RequestSerializer`. The serializer
> field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on
> the `User` instance. Original exception text was: 'User' object has no
> attribute 'documents'.

Увы, в упор не вижу решения, либо не понимаю свою ошибку или что-то еще. Прошу помочь!

***models.py***

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Request(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Document(models.Model):
    request = models.ForeignKey(Request, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField( max_length=100, null=True)

class DocumentLine(models.Model):
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    num = models.CharField( max_length=100, null=True)
```

***serializers.py***

```py
from .models import *
from rest_framework import serializers


class DocumentLineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = DocumentLine
        fields = ('pk','num',)


class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    documentlines = DocumentLineSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('pk', 'documentlines','name',)


class RequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    documents = DocumentSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Request
        fields = ('pk', 'documents', 'user',)
```

***views.py***

```py
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from .models import *
from .serializers import *
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET'])
def document_list_n(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        users = User.objects.all()
        doc_serializer = RequestSerializer(users, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(doc_serializer.data, safe=False)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        doc_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        doc_serializer = RequestSerializer(data=doc_data)
        if doc_serializer.is_valid():
            doc_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(doc_serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(doc_serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка, тк пытаетесь получить в сериализаторе поле модели, которого у этой модели нет. Используйте параметр `source`

```
class RequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    documents = DocumentSerializer(many=True, source='user.documents')

    class Meta:
        model = Request
        fields = ('pk', 'documents', 'user',)
```

[Источник](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)